# Contact card spam

Tags: contacts, spam, contacts.app

I'm getting contact cards in my Contacts.app that have the Apple logo, a name like "Apple inc." Or "Expedia" and then hundreds of emails listed under that contact.
I suspect this is someone trying to make me think they are Apple or Expedia when I view their emails, since their email address will be replaced with "Apple inc." When I view it in Mail.app.
Could this be a bug? What should I do? They seem to just come back after I delete them, but it's a real hassle to delete them since they freeze contacts.app because of the hundreds/thousands of email fields.

These are local contacts on a Mac running Yosemite. Here's a photo: https://i.stack.imgur.com/271Pz.jpg

Comment: I suggest you clarify /edit your question with information about whether the Contacts.app is running on a Mac, an iOS device; whether these rogue contact cards are stored in iCloud or locally. Clarify whether any apps have access to Contacts on iOS. Confirm whether you have tried deleting the rogue contacts using the iCloud.com web interface. Do the rogue contacts re-appear when you isolate all devices from the Internet, etc.

Comment: That photo is a pictures of water flasks.  Is that what you're seeing in Contacts?

Comment: I'm so sorry, wrong picture. Here it is: https://imgur.com/a/WjMOs

Answer (score 1):

I think you may have used the Contacts app's "Look for Duplicates" command. In my experience, contact cards that do not have first or last names are seen as duplicates of each other. If you choose to merge the "duplicate" contacts all data from the cards with no first or last name will merge into one card. It's definitely not the way to go!

Here is the wording in the Contacts app after you do "Look for Duplicates:"

"**Duplicate cards that have the same name but contain different information**, and cards containing duplicated information, were found. Do you want to merge duplicate cards and the duplicated information?" (emphasis by me).

I would call this either a bug or bad decision-making in the Contacts app. I would simply not use the Look for Duplicates command in Contacts as it can really cause trouble.

Comment: If that were the case, wouldn't the name of the merged contact (which Contacts.app creates to merge all the no-name contacts) be blank and there not be an icon? I feel that the existence of the contact name (Apple inc, Expedia, etc) and the icon (Apple logo) suggest that something different is going on. Thanks for your response!

Comment: You may be right. Give us more info if you can. I wonder whether there are a lot of notes at the bottom of the card will all of the phone numbers and emails. If so, it would seem your contacts have been merged somehow-- or corrupt. Are you able to edit the Contacts database, and do the edits stick?